# Prove that $7^{100}+3^{10}=8^{100}$ or $7^{100}+3^{10}<8^{100}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Prove that $7^{100}+3^{10}=8^{100}$ or $7^{100}+3^{10}<8^{100}$

I tried using some theorems of divisibility, to show that one divides the other, and the other also divides the first, but could not.

Comment: You can't prove it, because $7^{100} + 3^{10} < 8^{100}$. Much smaller.

Comment: @DanielFischer And how can I prove that is smaller?

Comment: Also, the two sides are not equal mod 4.

Comment: Fermat's Last Theorem also says this is impossible. (All three numbers are $10$th powers.)

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: Er... precisely why is anyone downvoting this or voting to close, if you please? Are we downvoting people for being wrong, now? The problem of determining which is smaller is legitimate.

Comment: @barto use of FLT >hero. (+1)

Comment: The question was already answered up, he is put on hold?

Comment: Another question that shows how stupid is the game of closing questions when they think, for some reason, the question is not up to some mysterious, level. It is ridiculous. Fortunately, all they do is useless as the questions always, absolutely always, get answered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$8^{100}=(7+1)^{100}\gt 7^{100}+100\cdot 7^{99} \cdot 1 \gt 7^{100}+3^{10}$

Comment: It seems very consistent, but did not get the first inequality could enlighten me, just for my understanding. Thank you very much. :)

Comment: @marcelolpjunior It's the binomial theorem with a bunch of terms lopped off.

Comment: There are $99$ missing terms in the binomial expansion.  All are positive, which justifies the $\gt$ sign.

Comment: I think I understand, I'll do some math here, but, beforehand, thank you.

Comment: The corresponding one with smaller exponent is $(7+1)^3=7^3+3\cdot 7^2\cdot 1 + 3\cdot 7 \cdot 1^2+1^3 \gt 7^3+3\cdot 7^2\cdot 1$

Comment: @JackM use of phrase *lopped off* (+1)

Answer (score 2):

**Imagine** dividing $7^{100}+3^{10}$ by $7^{100}$. The result is a **tiny** bit bigger than $1$.

Divide $8^{100}$ by $7^{100}$. We get $\left(\frac{8}{7}\right)^{100}$, which is a very big number, a lot bigger than $1$.

Thus $8^{100}$ is (an awful lot) bigger than $7^{100}+3^{10}$.

Answer (score 0):

If you list $7^x$ and $8^x$ you will notice that when $x$ is divisible by $4$, $7^x$ ends in $1$ and $8^x$ ends in $6$.  $$7^0=8^0=1$$ $$7^{4+j}=7^j*7^4$$ $$7^4 = 2401$$ $2401$ ends in $1$ as does $7^0$ and any number that ends in $1$ times any number than ends in 1 results in a number that also ends in $1$. This works for $8$ as $8^4$ ends in $6$ and $6$ has the same property.

In order for $7^x+y=8^x$ then $y$ must end in $5$ which is impossible for $3^z$ as any number that ends in $5$ is divisible by $5$.

Comment: Note that while Ross's answer is 100% correct, this shows that $8^{100}-7^{100}$ or even $8^{4x}-7^{4x}$ cannot be $3^y$ for any natural values of $x$ and $y$.